# Share compiled Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an Xcode project and I have to share it with other developers. They have to work on a small part of this, and compile. 
I started trying to convert a lot of code as framework, but it was beginning to be complex because of a lot of interweaving of #import.
Is possibile make project with some .o file e some that have to be build?
I'm open for any another way

NB: I forgot something fundamental: I want build some part of project because I don't want to permit to see how it is implemented

Comment: Have you tried creating a workspace with separate projects? You could split your project into smaller projects and work on them? I have never done something like this but I belive it should be doable.

Comment: I've tried to do this, when I wanted to convert some smaller parts in .framework, but I can't because there is a lot of import. So some "smaller part" become huge, and in the future I'll be not able to maintain updates

Answer (score 0):

You can put it to [github](https://github.com) as a free, open repository, or make it private, but have to pay. Then necessary part of it can be linked as a submodule.

It's possible without a github also, if you have some centralized place, where you can put it.

Comment: Additional info: There are also other services which offer free private repos. One is [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the code you want them to work on and create a git submodule. They can then clone and work on the git submodule and push their work to the repo as they progress. You can then keep pulling their changes on that submodule.

Check these resources

[Git Submodules: Adding, Using, Removing, Updating](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)

[Git Tools - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Essentially you will split your project into sub projects (doesnt need to be a new xcode project if there is no need for specific build settings) and track them as submodules in git.

So the scenario would be

- Determining the code they must work on or the sub "project"
- Create a submodule from that code (move the code to a folder in your project directory and initialize the submodule)
- Push the submodule to your repo, e.g. github/bitbucket
- Developers would pull down your submodule into their existing xcode project.

The submodule will contain only classes and files etc. that they need. All changes that they make to the submodule will be tracked and you can pull them and have continuous integration (some form).

Comment: I forgot to say that other can't see how I have implemented part of code

Comment: They cant see any of the code or only part of it? I meant that the part they can see could be a submodule.

Comment: They can not see most of the code, they have only to do little change to setting up the project before build

Comment: Code changes or project settings?

Comment: Can be both, change of some line of code and change at the project settings

Comment: You will have to expose some of the code to them then? Have you defined which classes they will need to modify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135671/discussion-between-pol-and-helium3).